# Query on a list of json in Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, json

I am using mysql 5.6 and it will not be feasible for me to upgrade it to 5.7. I have a table which stores json as an attribute. Attaching screenshot for reference.

[image: Here, the column policy_status contains status and values of different policies as json for each user.]

Here, the column policy_status contains status and values of different policies as json for each user.
How can I find the list of users, say, with appVersion' status as success and value = 1437.
I got a few references online but as I am new to stored procedures I am not able to reach a solution. I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not efficient at all but may can help you with ideas:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE
  (LOCATE('"employmentType":["status":"success"]', policy_status) > 0
   AND
   LOCATE('"value": 1', policy_status) > 0);
```

Using the `LOCATE` function you can see whether the field contains your desired `appVersion` and `value` strings. See **[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4f987/1)** here.

***Where the simple test data***:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  policy_status TEXT
);

INSERT INTO data (id, policy_status) VALUES
(1,'{"employmentType":["status":"success"], "value": 1}'),
(2,'{"employmentType":["status":"no"], "value": 1}'),
(3,'{"employmentType":["status":"no"], "value": 0}'),
(4,'{"employmentType":["status":"success"], "value": 0}'),
(5,'{"employmentType":["status":"no"], "value": 1}');
```

***gives the result***:

```
{"employmentType":["status":"success"], "value": 1}
```

Where both strings are found.

***UPDATE***:

Also if you can add `FULLTEXT` index for your `policy_status` column than you can use fulltext search in the `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE
   MATCH (policy_status) AGAINST ('+"employmentType:[status:success]" +"value: 1"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Note the `+` and `"` characters in `AGAINST(...)`. They are special boolean full-text search operators. ***[See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html)***.

> A leading or trailing plus sign indicates that this word must be
>   present in each row that is returned

and

> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (") characters matches
>   only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. The
>   full-text engine splits the phrase into words and performs a search in
>   the FULLTEXT index for the words. Nonword characters need not be
>   matched exactly.

If it is not an option in your case, you can use `LIKE` for matching the substrings:

```
...
WHERE
  (policy_status LIKE '%"employmentType":["status":"success"]%'
   AND
   policy_status LIKE '%"value": 1%');
```

See **[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5350df/19)** for both.